# How do I know whether the registered email is verified or not in firebase?

Tags: python, python-3.x, firebase, flask, pyrebase

I am making an app in the flask using `firebase authentication` with the `pyrebase` library.

following is the code I use for authentication...

```py
@app.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register_page():
    form = RegisterForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        data = {
            "username": form.username.data,
            "email_address": form.email_address.data,
            "password_hash": form.password.data
        }
        db.collection('users').document(form.username.data).set(data)

        def register():
            email = form.email_address.data
            password = form.password.data
            confirm_pass = form.confirm_password.data

            if password == confirm_pass:
                sign_in = auth.create_user_with_email_and_password(email, password)
                auth.send_email_verification(sign_in['idToken'])  # for email verification
                print("email verification sent")

        register()

        return redirect(url_for('market_page'))
    if form.errors != {}:   # if no errors occur from validators
        for err_msg in form.errors.values():
            print(f'there was an error creating the user {err_msg}')
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

I read most of the firebase documentation but I wasn't able to find any answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way in firebase to get if email is verified?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38595627/is-there-a-way-in-firebase-to-get-if-email-is-verified)

Comment: @tevemadar no it doesn't as firstly he is using javascript and I am using python, secondly, he is probably using `firebase-admin` SDK and I am using `pyrebase` for authentication.

Comment: I would still check for an `emailVerified` field.

Comment: @tevemadar yeah i checked, but it doesn't exist in `pyrebase` as it throws an error

Comment: @vanditvasa Please don't include tags in titles. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is an `emailVerified` in the result from calling the [`get_account_info` function](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L126).

I find it easiest to find this type of information by look at the Pyrebase [auth implementation](https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase/blob/master/pyrebase/pyrebase.py#L72-L164) and then finding the Google documentation for the REST API that is invoked, which is [`getAccountInfo` here](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/getAccountInfo).

Comment: If you don’t mind can you please provide a code snippet on the solution you are providing

Comment: With what I've included in my answer, finding examples can be done through search. See https://github.com/thisbejim/Pyrebase#get-account-information, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55798280/retrieving-user-info-using-pyrebase/55799293 and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=pyrebase+auth.get_account_info+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: I have read `readme.md` from Github and search google too but I am not getting satisfactory results

Comment: The question I linked in my previous comment shows an example of calling `getAccountInfo` in `user_info = auth.get_account_info(token)`. If you're having trouble making that work, edit your question to show what you've tried already.